# Accept calls on external cell phones - FreePBX Distro

Tags: centos, voip, asterisk, telephony, freepbx

We installed FreePBX distro last week and configured it so that when someone calls in, it goes to all the phones so someone here can answer the call.  After trying all the internal extensions, it rolls over to a ring group with Zach's cell phone number in it, then the next ring group called Pause which does nothing and has the number of 0, then the next ring group of Tom's cell phone.
If it still has not been answered then it goes to a ring group that has the internal "voicemail" number in it. Here, it leaves a voicemail and then emails us the wav file.

When the system calls the cell phones the person being called has to dial `1` to confirm the call - Zach hasn't been able to answer the call by pressing 1, but Tom can.

We tried Switching the ring group pointing to Zach to point to a third person, and they were able to confirm calls, so it must be Zac's blackberry that has issues.

Well, we switch it back, don't change anything else (intentionally). Call in now, and it says "please wait while we transfer you" just like normal, but never rings either cell phone and basically goes straight to voicemail after trying the internal extensions. If we dial JUST the external phone ring groups from our internal phone, it goes to the phone just fine.

So in summary, something's killing it when going from the ring group for the internal phones to the external cell phone ring groups. What are some settings to look for on this? I can look into settings, I just can't test much until this weekend.

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with your PBX not receiving/processing DTMF tones. There are a lot of possible causes for this - if you're using a VOIP trunk (sip or IAX) you should talk to the trunk provider. If you're using direct telco connections (T1 or POTS line cards) I would suspect the blackberry (try another device? Determine if it's cell-carrier specific?)

Comment: Re: your ring group woes, (a) check your Asterisk logs. The call has to be going somewhere.  (b) Please for the love of sanity simplify your ring group structure. You've got way too much jumping around going on - you can accomplish what you want with 2 ring groups and a voicemail box.  Model it on your test/development system.

Comment: I don't think we have any way around having that many ring groups. It was set up by a previous guy, so I don't know what the function of "Pause" is, but other than that, we want the following to occur: 1. Ring office reception desk, 2. Ring support (not "important" people) phones 3. Ring ALL phones (in case support is busy with a call), 4. Ring cell phone of IT guy (in case everyone's out of office) 5. Ring IT guy #2 (in case IT guy is busy) 6. Voicemail.  WE have people working here all hours, so how else would I accomplish what we want? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Giving you a new phone system structure is way beyond the scope of a Q&A site (certainly way beyond comments), but here's a hint: Ring groups can be set up to call numbers in sequence ("ringall" is not the only ring strategy). It sounds like you inherited a mess though, so after you fix the DTMF problem you should start looking to straighten it out (like I said, model it in dev - way easier than trying to do it in 300 characters of text)

Comment: OK, so after more testing I found part of it. It DOES confirm calls, so it's not the particular phone. EDIT: It confirms calls ONLY when the "Destination if no answer" is set to Hangup and not if that's set to move on to the next guy's cell phone (next ring group)

Also, I had it working this way, and simply changed the name of the ring group and reloaded Asterisk and it killed it. Tried recreating ring group, and as long as you don't change anything it works, but even a minor change kills it even if you change back. So somewhere, somehow, the GUI is lying or duplicating to error.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to queues instead of ring-groups for this task, you can confirm calls in queues just make the first queue failover to the second and make the cell phones call in an order.

```
5555551111,1 
5555551112,2
```

More on queues module
http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FPG/Queues+Module+User+Guide

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked that none of the do-not-disturb (or other options that might send a call directly to voicemail) are set on that extension? There are some FreePBX feature codes that you can dial on that extension to enable/disable these features (I forget what they are at the moment, but you can look up what they're set to in the FreePBX interface).

Comment: For the cell phone groups (external numbers) this wouldn't matter - you can't set DnD on a ring group (it's an extension thing), and the external numbers are de-facto *not* extensions...

Comment: Checked w/in the gui and none of these are set.